# how to deal with complicated query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pymongo

I use mongodb to save the temporal and spatial data, and the document item is structured as follows:

```
doc = { time:t,
        geo:[x,y]
      }
```

If the different of two docs are defined as:

```
dist(doc1, doc2) = |t1-t2| + |x1-x2| + |y1 - y2|
```

How can I query the documents by mongodb and sort the results by their distance to a given document doc0 ={ time:t0, geo:[x0,y0] }?

thanks

Comment: You can use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) for a complicated query like this.  See the `$add` and `$subtract` [arithmetic projection operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating the distance manually, you could trust mongodb with that task. Mongodb has [built in geospatial query support](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-Querying).

This would look like this:

```
db.docs.find( { 
  "time": "t0", 
  "geo" : { $near : [x0,y0] } 
} ).limit(20)
```

The result would be all documents near the given location `[x0,y0]`, automatically ordered by distance to that point.